# Excel SUMPRODUCT to find the % of a whole number

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

the Excel SUMPRODUCT function can be quite powerful in different scenario including

- Doing the product
- Sum with condition
- Division
- Weighted average
- Calculating the % given two sets of value
- Finding text in a cell given a range of values

But what I couldn't make out of it is to find the contribution ratio (%) of two numbers.

Say something like

| A | B | Contribution % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 414 | 24 | 5,80% |
| 754 | 36 | 4,78% |
|  |  | 5,13% |

Can I use the SUMPRODUCT to obtain the above Contribution (B/A) but across the whole set?
A `=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B2;0,1/A1:B2)` gives a value next to it, but not the correct one.

Perhaps it's me that I'm overlooking to something, or simply asking for something impossible.

Thanks for feeding me in.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/A2,B2)`

Comment: Thanks ... I just made it clear, but I need the calc across the whole set of data, not just the individual lines. So 60 / 1168 in this example. I guess I have to introduce a SUM within the SUMPRODUCT

Comment: Why does it need to be sumproduct? Can't you just say =A1/sum($a$1:$b$2) ? And then extend the formula?

Comment: No particular reason in using the sumproduct. I was more interested in "can this be done" rather than achieving the result at this stage

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT()` only ever returns a single result so if you want to keep using it then either you need to copy it down, or else use an Excel table. _If_ you have dynamic arrays (since you neglected to tag your version of Excel) then you can avoid _all_ functions since your issue is, simply, one of basic division, i.e. `=B2:B3/A2:A3`